# How to perform segue with navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I just want to perform segue with a back button on top.

```
@IBAction func onFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstSegue", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func onSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: go on your storyboard choose your `viewController` then on menu bar click `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two view controllers, ViewControllerOne and ViewControllerTwo.

You could do that programmatically or using storyboards.

Since you seem to be using @IBOutlet I will assume you want to do it using storyboards.

First open up your Main.storyboard and make sure that ViewControllerOne (the controller you want to segue from) is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

If it's not, you can do that by clicking on your View Controller, then click on Editor in the top menu bar, go to Embed In and select Navigation Controller.

Then you can create a segue using the Interface Builder by doing control + click on the little yellow icon at the top of ViewControllerOne (**not the Navigation Controller**) & drag to ViewControllerTwo in the Interface Builder.

Now click on the segue that just got created, and type an `identifier` of your choice in the Attributes Inspector.

Then in your ViewControllerOne class, you can just perform the segue using the @IBOutlet as you mentioned :

```
@IBAction func onFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "your_segue_identifier", sender: self)
}
```

Just make sure that the segue identifiers match, and everything should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You need redefine target and action for your current navigation item

```
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target = self
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(self.onFirst(_:))
```